# Firebase FCM token - When to send to server?

Tags: android, mysql, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Okay so I have an app which on first start takes you through a few welcoming slides, then takes you to a login/register page and then to `MainActivity`.

I have just implemented `FCM` and the services generate a `token` **before** any of those pages have been seen by the user. How could I make it so that the service runs **after** I get to `MainActivity`?

The problem is I'm trying to send the token as soon as it is refreshed to the `MySQL DB` to the appropriate user account, but since the user hasn't signed in yet, that is `null` and my message to the server fails. What's a good way to design this? I thought of saving the token in `SharedPreferences` and sending it to the server after the user has logged in but that creates lots of complications when the token is refreshed at some later point?!

**Possible solution**:

I'm not sure I completely understand how the 2 services run but say in `onTokenRefresh` I just save the token into `SharedPreferences` and in MainActivity I get the value from `SP` and then I send it to the server. In that case when the token is refreshed the new value will immediately go into `SharedPreferences` again. But I would still need to check if it's a new value in SP and then reupload it to the server. This is confusing!

Comment: http://engineering.letsnurture.com/firebase-cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes FCM token is generated automatically. But try to see this in a different angle.

This is how I handled it.

Let FCM generate token as soon as your app starts. OnTokenRefresh will be called and you just save it in your preferences as:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance(this).setValue(getString(R.string.firebase_cloud_messaging_token), token);
    
   // To implement: Only if user is registered, i.e. UserId is available in preference, update token on server.
   int userId = SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance(this).getIntValue(getString(R.string.user_id), 0);
   if(userId != 0){
       // Implement code to update registration token to server
   }
}
```

Hope you are clear with the way. Ask if you need more clearance on it.

**Edit**

Using the new Firebase SDK (21.0.0) , you need to override  `onNewToken()` method instead of  `onTokenRefresh()`

```
 @Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    sendRegistrationToServer(s);
}
```

Comment: So I could the same thing but also in my MainActivity on first start send the token to server because the only way to use the app is to register and the first time the service starts theres no userid so it won't be sent to the server. I guess that's my solution. Don't you send it to the server the first time you get a token? Or you just do it later too but didn't include the code?

Answer (score 14):

Note that you can always retrieve the token with:

```
FirebaseInstanceID.getInstance().getToken();
```

This will return `null` if the token has not yet been generated or the token if it has been generated. In your case it is very likely that the token will be generated by the time the user has signed in. So you should be able to send it to your app server as soon as the user has signed in. If it is not available then you would send it in the onTokenRefresh callback as Chintan Soni mentioned.

**Edit**

Using the new Firebase SDK (21.0.0) , you will get your token this way :

```
 FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstallationTokenResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstallationTokenResult> task) {
              if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                  return;
              }
              // Get new Instance ID token
              String token = task.getResult().getToken();

          }
      });
```

You better add a listener for more handling on the response .

Answer (score 7):

We handled it like this:

1. Our server create/update the token value against a user id (primary key)
2. Use 2 SharedPreferences

   1. String - token String
   2. Boolean (updated) - whether token is updated on server or not.

In case of token refresh we update the token string and set the boolean to false.
Later whenever user login each time we check for boolean (updated), if that is false - we attach the current token to his id and send it to server and set updated to true.

Comment: is there a way to get the token just using the email of a user (all in the server side)?

Comment: @Andrea firebase will not know email of the user right? So how you will query against it?

Comment: Firebase user holds some values of the user, one of them is the email `https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users`

Answer (score 0):

**December 2020 update :** Using the new Firebase SDK (21.0.0) you can get it by overriding `onNewToken()` method :

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    sendRegistrationToServer(s);
}
```

Or by `FirebaseInstallations.getInstance()` within your scope :

```
FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstallationTokenResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstallationTokenResult> task) {
              if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                  return;
              }
              // Get new Instance ID token
              String token = task.getResult().getToken();

          }
      });
```