# How can I send Firebase cloud message token to my server when I try Loggin/SignUp?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am not android developer(I am backend developer) And I try use FCM(Firebase Cloud Messages) in android project.

I have next problem: After success loged in I need receive FCM token and add it to user profile. But Token received asynchronously and in service.

I read many articles and documentations but I not understand how it worket. In all articles I see examples like this:

[image]

And in [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?authuser=0) I see this:

[image]

And nobody not write how can I implement this method:

```
sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
```

I faund [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38344621/4781349) but author write:

```
if(userId != 0){
       // Implement code to update registration token to server
   }
```

How can I mplement code to update registration token to server???

[next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38347611/4781349) in this questions this is the most detailed of all that I found. but still do not understand how to implement my logic?

My logic:

1. User open app and enter to StartActivity
2. In startActivity I check user authToken
3. If authToken == null -> open LoginFragment
4. If authToken != null -> open MainActivity
5. Indefinitely  I can receive FCM token in `onTokenRefresh` method.
6. If I send this token to My server immediately - It can happen that I'm not logged in and I should not send this token to server. Ok. I can check my authToken. if authToken != null -> I can sent FCM token to server else I save this token to sharedPreferences.(as advised in the comments that I cited as an example). But what I need do if inthis time my authToken == null(I not logged in)? I can only save it to sharedPreferences with flag - `sended == false`.  but when will I send it now? the next time you try to sign in to the application? Then I have several places scattered around the application, and a bunch of checks. when I try to log in, I need to check sended true or false and if false how can I send it token with login and password, or another request?

Answer (score 0):

You can not be sure about when the token is getting refreshed. All what you need to do is to write the token in database somewhere under uId node.

Answer (score 0):

- In your onTokenRefresh() save the token on sharedpreferences Like this :

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.your_app_nam), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
          editor.putString(getString(R.string.fcm_token),your_refreshed_token);
  editor.commit();
- and then in your loging request you can get the token like this:

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.your_app_nam), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  String fcmToken = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.your_refreshed_token),"");

I hope it helps you.